# Custom ID elements + Custom CSS

Tags: css

Okay so I edited the following...

```
<div id="rt-utility"><div class="rt-block fp-roksprocket-grids-utility title5 jmoddiv">
```

by simply putting the following into my custom.css

```
#rt-utility .rt-block {CODE HERE}
```

but when I try to change...

```
<div id="rt-sideslider-overlay"><header id="rt-header-surround">
```

with

```
#rt-sideslider-overlay .header-rt-header-surround {CODE HERE}
```

it doesn't work... Does this have something to do with the fact its a header id and not div id??

Comment: This should work: `#rt-sideslider-overlay #rt-header-surround`.

Comment: @emmanuel is right, its the difference between ID (`#`) and class (`.`)

Comment: Use just: `#rt-header-surround { // rules here }`

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
#rt-header-surround {}
```

Answer (score 1):

a little mistake:

replace

```
#rt-sideslider-overlay .header-rt-header-surround {CODE HERE}
```

with

```
#rt-sideslider-overlay header#rt-header-surround {CODE HERE}
```

because the tag name selector is just

```
header
```

read more in css selectors:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html